# How to set focus on a section of my web page and then scroll down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, protractor

Using Protractor, I would like to first set focus on a left panel on my web page, and then scroll down in order to click on a filter.

How can I do this using the Protractor syntax?

Here is my HTML:

```html
<section id="filters" style="height: 266px; overflow: hidden;" tabindex=
"5076">
    <div class="ng-binding" id="currentSearchTitle">
        Current search
    </div>

    <div id="currentSearch">
        <div id="searchBlock">
            <div id="jobTypeBlock">
                <div class="ng-binding" id="jobTypeTitle">
                    Filter by job type
                </div>

                <div class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="ng-scope">
                            <div class="ng-scope">
                                <div class="ng-scope">
                                    <div class="ng-scope">
                                        <div class="ng-scope"></div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To set the focus on your panel, you can maybe click on it:

```
element(by.id('filters')).click();
```

Then to scroll to your filter, you can execute a client-side script:

```
var filter = browser.findElement(by.id('jobTypeTitle'));
var scrollIntoView = function () {
  arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
};
browser.executeScript(scrollIntoView, filter);
```

You can have a look at the [webdriverjs documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js?name=2.34.0#398).

Comment: It is not working for me due to this issue (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1846), even though it is a good approach

Comment: This worked for me in Protractor v2.5.1. Thanks a million!

Comment: The link redirects [to GitHub](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive#398). It says *"This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only."*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too:
`browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", basePage.faqText.getWebElement());`

I does the magic in one line.

`basePage.faqText` is the element that I want to scroll here.