# Protractor not scrolling to test element

Tags: protractor, ionic-framework

Trying to write some protractor tests for ionic, realized the selector `element( by.css('.selector'));` no longer scrolls to the element. Which when it's not visible in the browser, automatically fails the test.

Took me awhile to figure it out. Using a `ptor.sleep(2000)` to delay the page after `browser.get('domain');` and then If I scroll through the sections where the elements are being tested, they pass (as expected).

I believe this has something to do with ionic taking over scroll events.

Has anyone ran into this before or have some sort of scrollTo implementation for all elements?

sample test

```
"use strict";

/* Tests */

var ptor = protractor.getInstance();

describe( "Register page", function ()
{
    browser.get( "#/register" );

    ptor.sleep(2000);

    it( "Check SMS Preference", function ()
    {

        var smsLabelConfirm = element( by.css( ".sms-confirm" ) ),
            smsLabelDeny = element( by.css( ".sms-deny" ) ),
            smsInputConfirm = element ( by.id( "sms-confirm" ) ),
            smsInputDeny = element ( by.id( "sms-deny" ) );

            smsLabelConfirm.click();
            expect( smsInputConfirm.getAttribute( "checked" ) ).toBe( "true" );
            expect( smsInputDeny.getAttribute( "checked" ) ).toBe( null );

            smsLabelDeny.click();
            expect( smsInputConfirm.getAttribute( "checked" ) ).toBe( null );
            expect( smsInputDeny.getAttribute( "checked" ) ).toBe( "true" );

    } );
});
```

Comment: I have experienced the same problem with a regular angular application. I was unable to read an element attribute when it was not visible. When you perform an action on the input it automatically scrolls for an angular app running in chromedriver. What browser are you using to test?

Comment: @AndresD Using Chrome. It worked on another project, as soon as I ported it into ionic it stopped. Wondering if the framework is capturing/manipulating scroll events.

Comment: Wondering if it may also be a jQlite issue.

Comment: yes, there is [some sort of scrollTo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571852/protractor-scroll-down), but you may have to add a function which returns an elements location

Comment: @nilsK It's just weird because in my other project, it automatically scrolls to the element. I'll look into some global scrollTo function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ended up using a variation of the answer provided here: [How to set focus on a section of my web page then scroll down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933268/how-to-set-focus-on-a-section-of-my-web-page-then-scroll-down)

Changed it so the function just takes the element as an argument for reusability. Seems to be working.

```
var ptor = protractor.getInstance();

var scrollIntoView = function (element) {
  arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
};

describe( "Register page", function ()
{
    browser.get( "#/register" );

    ptor.sleep(2000);

    it( "Check SMS Preference", function ()
    {

        var smsLabelConfirm = element( by.css( ".sms-confirm" ) ),
            smsLabelDeny = element( by.css( ".sms-deny" ) ),
            smsInputConfirm = element ( by.id( "sms-confirm" ) ),
            smsInputDeny = element ( by.id( "sms-deny" ) );

            browser.executeScript(scrollIntoView, smsLabelConfirm);

            smsLabelConfirm.click();
            expect( smsInputConfirm.getAttribute( "checked" ) ).toBe( "true" );
            expect( smsInputDeny.getAttribute( "checked" ) ).toBe( null );

            smsLabelDeny.click();
            expect( smsInputConfirm.getAttribute( "checked" ) ).toBe( null );
            expect( smsInputDeny.getAttribute( "checked" ) ).toBe( "true" );

    } );
});
```

Comment: Odd, using `scrollIntoView` gives me a max call stack error.

Comment: @AshleyCoolman I had this issue as well, but I solved it by tacking `.getWebElement()` onto the element I was passing into the argument. That way the `WebElement` gets passed in rather than the wrapper for it.

Comment: This answer has a mistake in it - should be changed to `element.scrollIntoView();`.

That still didn't work for me, but when you add in @Aaron's suggestion of using `.getWebElement()`, everything works!

Comment: It works using: 
`browser.executeScript(function () {
       arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
      }, yourElement.getWebElement());`