# Protractor: Scroll down doesnot work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protractor

I have an button on bottom of my page that is visible when user scrolls down. Because of this, protractor tests give me an error UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (94, 188). I tried using browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,1000)'); which worked in Firefox but not in chrome. Any help will be appreciated.

I have also tried below code but didn't work in chrome.

```
var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
ptor.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,1000);').then(function () {
  page.saveButton.click();
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set focus on a section of my web page then scroll down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933268/how-to-set-focus-on-a-section-of-my-web-page-then-scroll-down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try with browser.executeScript(commonService.scrollIntoView, );

then in my commonService file I had:

scrollIntoView  :
                function(){
                    arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
                }

I needed this scroll functionality at many places(assuming you would also), i had placed it in a commonService file. This works for me in Chrome!
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier way to scroll to an element, it can be used if want to focus the particular element.

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element).perform();
```

After that the browser will be focusing the element.